# Runtime of this function in Theta

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

`Func5(n)
1 s=0;
2 i=6;
3 while (i < n^(5/2)) do
4    j=4;
5    while (j < 5i) do
6        s=s + i - j;
7        j=j + 9 ; 
8    end
9    i=4 * i ; 
10 end
11 return (s);`

So far I got the upper bound for this function is O(n^(5/2)log(n)) and I am not sure if or not this is the closest upper bound we can get. And I have no clue how to show the lower bound with the same function.

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Our [reference question may help](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis).

Comment: As OP is out of reach, I am voting to close it as duplicate.